# Append value from cookie to URL in Django

Tags: django, url-rewriting

I have a value the user sets via a cookie and I want this value to be appended onto the URL after the user sets it.  How can I enable this?  Any ideas are welcome as I'm not so sure how to go about this.

Comment: It's not clear what you want: do you want to compose new urls (reverse) or to redirect the user to the new url with this value?

Comment: Sorry for being a bit vague, but what I want to do is redirect the user to the new URL with this value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an ineffective solution, but what if you write a view to check for the existance of the cookie, if it doesn't exist let them set it. If it does exist, HttpRedirect them to url + cookie-value. And add a line in your urls.py to match those urls.

Comment: This sounds like a sensible solution given the described problem, but the described problem seems like a symptom of something being really badly designed. OP, be warned.

Comment: @rz: I'll keep your warning in mind...thank you for the heads up